# How to filter, summarize and reshape the dataframe based on criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'column1_T1':[1,0,0,1,1],'column1_issues':     ['Comment1','abc','pqr','Comment2','Comment1'],'column2_T2':[0,0,1,0,1],'column2_issues':['OK','abc','Comment3','efg','Comment3']})
```

it will look like the following
df

```
column1_T1  column1_issues  column2_T2    column2_issues
1                Comment1    0                 OK
0                  abc       0                 abc
0                  pqr       1                 Comment3
1              Comment2      0                 efg
1              Comment1      1                 Comment3
```

Columns with suffixes T1,T2 and so on contain either 1 or 0.

Columns with suffixes "issues" contain comments about the corresponding issues.
I only have to consider 1s in columns with suffixes T1/T2 and so on, and the corresponding issues in column1_issues,column2_issues and so on.

Now I want to count the number of 1s in column1_T1,column2_T2, and unique comments in column1_issues,column2_issues corresponding to the 1s in column1_T1,column2_T2 respectively, and get it in the following format

```
column_labels     count   issue1     issue2
column1_issues     3      comment1   commen2
column2_issues     2      comment3
```

I have tried groupby and crosstab,but I am not able to get it

```
df3=df.groupby(['column1_T1', 'column1_issues'])['column1_T1'].count().unstack().fillna(0)

df3['Total'] =df3.loc[[1]].sum(axis=1)
```

but this is far from what I want. I am really stuck here.

I want my final dataframe in the following format as mentioned above
in the following format

```
column_labels     count   issue1     issue2
column1_issues     3      comment1   commen2
column2_issues     2      comment3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter first column for each group for `1` values, get second column for 2 column `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([x.iloc[x.iloc[:, 0].values == 1,1].to_frame('issues').assign(lab=x.columns[1])
               for i, x in df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
print (df1)
     issues             lab
0  Comment1  column1_issues
1  Comment2  column1_issues
2  Comment1  column1_issues
3  Comment3  column2_issues
4  Comment3  column2_issues
```

Then remove duplicates, add helper column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), last use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for count column by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df2 = df1.drop_duplicates().copy()
df2['g'] = df1.groupby('lab').cumcount().add(1)
df2 = df2.pivot('lab','g','issues').add_prefix('issue')
df2.insert(0, 'count', df1['lab'].value_counts())

df2 = df2.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df2)
              lab  count    issue1    issue2
0  column1_issues      3  Comment1  Comment2
1  column2_issues      2  Comment3       NaN
```